# Minecraft Modding: Make entity teleport up when hit by a certain item

Tags: minecraft-forge

I am learning to create minecraft mods. 
I would like to know how to make an entity teleport upwards when hit by a certain item. I have already made the item.

Answer (score 1):

Override either `Item#onLeftClickEntity(ItemStack, EntityPlayer, Entity)` or `Item#hitEntity(ItemStack, EntityLivingBase, EntityLivingBase)`. In that method set the target's Y position to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to use onLeftClickEntity. in the item class for your item, make a 
onLeftClickEntity method. inside that method, it should be as simple as using motionY. untested though, and for 1.12.2.